# Rotation toward the movement direction of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have camera which is moving on spline one by one. One complete camera path (spline) consist of several spline and I moving my object on that spline using MegaShape Script package.

I have [LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) my camera to spline object but each time spline object change cam feel jerk. So, How can I make it smooth or is there any smart way to keep rotation of the camera towards the movement direction of an object

Comment: it is looking to wrong direction not forward transform.LookAt(transform.forward);

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake.  One way perhaps is to determine the tangent at a point along the spline and have the camera smoothly rotate towards it

Comment: how it is possible