# Smoothly LookAt different object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As picture depicted my camera moving on path I want to lookAt path's different object smoothly. Currently I have tried

```
trasnform.LooAt(activePath.gameObject.transform);
```

but it producing jerky result. Object suddenly lookAt to next object with jerk! how to avoid it. I searched and found this solution but it also not working

```
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(activePath.gameObject.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`void SmoothLookAt(Vector3 newDirection){
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection), Time.deltaTime);
 }`

Pass in the Vector3 position of the new look at target to this method and it will smoothly look at the target.

e.g. `SmoothLookAt(activePath.gameObject.transform)`

Comment: Try adding a multiplier to `Time.deltaTime` to slow the movement down to pin point your issue. I fear that there are other scripts of which are causing an issue. You may need to post more of an example of your script

Comment: actually I am using megaShape package which get spl format spline then i am moving my camera on those spline one by one. for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249480/rotation-toward-the-movement-direction-of-object

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make a smooth translation. The parameters are

- Object to be translated transform,
- Final position and
- lookAt transform

```
private const float ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_SECONDS = 5f;

private IEnumerator SmoothTranslation(Transform startTransform, Vector3 finalPosition, Transform lookAtTransform){
        float currentDelta = 0;

        // Store initial values, because startTransform is passed by reference
        var startPosition = startTransform.position;
        var startRotation = startTransform.rotation;

        while (currentDelta <= 1f) {
            currentDelta += Time.deltaTime / ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_SECONDS;

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, finalPosition, currentDelta);

            if (lookAtTransform != null) {
                // HACK Trick: 
                // We want to rotate the camera transform at 'lookAtTransform', so we do that.
                // On every frame we rotate the camera to that direction. And to have a smooth effect we use lerp.
                // The trick is even when we know where to rotate the camera, we are going to override the rotation 
                // change caused by `transform.lookAt` with the rotation given by the lerp operation. 
                transform.LookAt(lookAtTransform);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, transform.rotation, currentDelta);
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogWarning("CameraZoomInOut: There is no rotation data defined!");
                transform.rotation = originalCameraRotation;
            }

            yield return null;
        }

    }
```